# How to reference host variable in Ansible template?

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have the following Ansible project structure:

```
├── demo.yml
├── hosts
├── group_vars
│   └── all
└── roles
    ├── common
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── templates
    │       └── init.j2
```

Inside 'hosts', I have:

```
[primary]
server1
[secondary]
server2
```

In roles/common/templates/init.j2, I want to be able to refer to the **[primary]** group variable. Since Ansible uses Jinja2 for its [template module](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html). I was directed to [this Jinja2 doc](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html).

I tried:

```
print("{{ group['primary'] }}")
```

But it will return:

```
['server1']
```

Right now I can only get it within a loop:

```
{% for host in groups['primary'] %}
    print("{{ host }}")
{% endfor %}
```

It will return what I want:

```
server1
```

**But how do I get this result without using a loop?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
groups['primary'][0]
```

or just print group and you should be able to see how the data is store.

Hope this helps!